# Setting flask environment variables in a shell script

Tags: python, flask

all

As flask-script document said they are no longer to maintain it,

thus I am trying to use flask cli (Command Line Interface) to activate my flask app.

When I run the following flask cli commands one by one at my terminal, they worked fine for me.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PWD:flask_api/
$ export FLASK_APP=flask_api/app
$ export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
$ flask run
```

The problem is that it seems not that efficient every time I tried to start my flask app.

so I came up with writing them into a shell scripts (that said run_flask.sh)

the content in run_flask.sh is:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD:flask_api/
export FLASK_APP=flask_api/app
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
flask run
```

and I simply run `source run_flask.sh`
and the result showed and did not start to run flask:

```
"* Serving Flask app "flask_api/app
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

".ror: Could not import "src.flask_api.app
```

I am not sure what's happening,

could any one tell me why flask could not import my flask app while I tried to run it with shell scripts? Great Thanks!

ps. I declare flask app instance in **flask_api/base_api/**init**.py,**

and **app.py** is in **flask_api/** folder, app.py would import the app instance from base_api

(I used CentOS7 as the OS)

Comment: A better question is why you're doing any of that in the first place. You can define your port in the code and run it directly, assuming you have a function you can call to start the server. Why are you using the flask cli?

Comment: @JaredSmith First of all, thanks for replying to my question.  The main reason I used flask cli is to avoid some reloading problems which might cause by using "python app.py" directly to start flask service. My flask did not occur reloading problem now, but I am not sure it will not in the future. Therefore I would like to switch to the better way to start my flask service